# Eclipse 3.7 Android R.java missing?

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file, eclipse-adt

My problem is that `eclipse` is not generating a `R.java` file even right after creating a new android application project so there should be no errors in my `xml` files.

I double checked to see if there was any errors with the `xml` files. Also I have cleaned and rebuilt my project manually.

I'm using `eclipse 3.7` and `adt 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395`

**Edit:**
Here is a screen from eclipse
[image]

Comment: In situation like this there is usually some problem with the layout code and definition, the XML part.

Comment: you may be using that portion code of which are available on the later sdk.

Comment: Like I said I have tripple checked those files for any errors and there are none.

Comment: @BlackDevil What do you mean?

Comment: When u create a new project, can u give target as least possible sdk and check whether R is generated or not

Comment: I set target to API 10 since it has a vast majority of the market in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think that your layout xml and manifest.xml is correct than might be your Android plugin is corrupted. Try to re-install the ADT plugin. It happened to me once. Thanks.

Comment: Argh I hope that I don't need do that I have almost reached the data cap from my ISP.

Comment: I just realized I copied my `SDK` from a `32bit` installation of Ubuntu to a `64bit` version. Which would explain why i'm having issues. Am I correct?

Comment: i think 32bit to 64bit shuldn't have any issues. Android SDK is not dependent. the only thing that SDK requirements says about Unix is that "64-bit distributions must be capable of running 32-bit applications".. hope this helps.. thanks

Comment: Well since `Ubuntu` is probably the most popular `Linux distro` so I would think it's `64bit` version would support `32bit` applications.

Comment: Proof for case in [point](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+question/197116).

Answer (score 0):

You did confirm you don't have the line "import android.R" in your source right?  I had that happen to me early on and the only way to fix it was to know to manually delete that import line.

Comment: Yes I don't have the import line.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First Clean your Project, from Project ---> Clean.

**2.** Check is there any Error in the xml file.

**3. Never** import android.R

**////// Edited  ///////////////**

Go below in your `Problem tab`....

**Delete all the Errors in it, and also delete all the Warnings....**

I am showing the warning deletion

[image: PIC]

Comment: Eclipse won't let me delete them.

Comment: They are getting deleted..as they are lots of them..u are not able to note it.... try enlarging that error window, and do it... its very possible to do it.

Comment: In the context menu delete is greyed out.

Comment: Look below in your IDE there is a Problem section... click on the very first Description section, R_Click... then delete... See the pic in my answer

Comment: Ahh I see now I was selecting the parent element in the tree before.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once. In my case, the problem was the workspace. Just create a new workspace in Eclipse and try creating a new project. It worked for me.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Sadly I've moved on to android studio now. But I hope this will help those who come across the problem for other people.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem yesterday and finally solved it. Especially the problem arouse when restarted the IDE. Because the R.java will be regenerated when project reloaded. I try to clean the project and rebuild. But no luck.
If you indeed are sure that the layout xml is correct, you can try to delete the project and reimport it. BTW, I found the Google adt bundle which is a android development IDE provided by Google has no R.java missing problem. The same source in eclipse+adt_plugin always has the R.java missing problem. But the same source did not has the problem in adt bundle.

Comment: Thx for the response. I have restarted my project and used the new ADT provided by google and everything works like new.

Comment: why did someone downvote my answer? I have been not encountered R.java missiong problem since I have used adt bundle IDE provided by Google. In fact, the R.java missing problem is due to the compatibility of eclipse and adt plugin.